# Ignore duplicates in regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex pattern that searches for words in a text file. How do I ignore duplicates?

For instance, take a look at this code

```
$pattern = '/(lorem|ipsum|daboom|pahwal|ababaga)/i';
$num_found = preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );

echo "$num_found match(es) found!";
echo "Matched words: " . implode( ',', $matches[0] );
```

If I have more than one say *lorem* in the article, the output will be something like this

```
5 matches found!
Matched words: daboom,lorem,lorem,lorem,lorem
```

I want the pattern to only find the first occurrence, and ignore the rest, so the output should be:

```
2 matches found!
Matched words: daboom,lorem
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do an [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on `$matches[0]`. And maybe an [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with `strtolower` if you want the unique to be case insensitive.

```
$pattern = '/(lorem|ipsum|daboom|pahwal|ababaga)/i';
preg_match_all( $pattern, $string, $matches );
$matches = $matches[0]?array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $matches[0])):array();

echo count($matches)." match(es) found!";
echo "Matched words: " . implode( ',', $matches );
```

Comment: *slaps forehead* Why didn't I think of that?